# Illegal offset type in isset or empty laravel cart

Tags: laravel, cart

How to add to the cart? When I want to add to the cart I see this error.

I have this code that was working initially but does not work after I restarted my computer.

But I get this error.

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

```
    public function addToCart(Product $product)
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);
        if (Cart::has($product)) {
            if(Cart::count($product) < $product->inventory)
                Cart::update($product, 1);
        } else {
            if(isset($cart[$product])) {
                $cart[$product]['quantity']++;
            } else {
                $cart[$product] = [
                    "title" => $product->title,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "image" => $product->image,
                    "price" => $product->price,
                ];
                Cart::put(
                    [
                        'quantity' => 1,
                    ],
                    $product
                );
            }
        }
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, you are using `$product` as an index of `$cart`'s array, but `$product` is an object, so it must either be an `integer` or a `string` to be able to be used as an index on an array...

Maybe you want to use `$product->id` or something like that